# To throw error when arguments are passed without double quotes

Tags: bash, error-handling

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#myscript.sh



if [[ "$1" == "" ]]
then
    echo "Hello, "
elif ! [[ "$1" =~ "*[a-z]*[A-z]" ]]
then
    echo "Usage: error_handling.sh $1"
elif [[ "$1" != "" ]]
then
    echo "Hello, $1"
else
    echo "Usage: error_handling.sh $1"
fi
```

The intention of the above script is to throw (custom) error when script is run like this:

```
./myscript.sh Alice
```

i.e. it shows error as:

```
"Usage: error_handling.sh Alice"
```

But if the same script is run like this:

```
./myscript.sh "Alice"
```

it should  show:

```
Hello, Alice
```

But it throws the custom error statement for both the conditions.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: This cannot work, because your script does not know about the quotes. They are interpreted and removed before your script runs. They are not part of `$1`.

Comment: Your script has terribly wrong logic. But, as @pLumo said, double quotes are removed from the parameters when you call your script. You should use the command `./myscript.sh \"Alice\"` to prevent bash remove them.

Comment: I am completely new to Bash. I just started learning today. Could you please show how to implement that?